# How to see GoRouter navigation stack's top element without poping it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I am building a flutter app. I have a place in the app where you can make infinite loops with

```
GoRouter.of(context).push(...);
```

I mean you can navigate to Screen A and then to B and then to A. There are many screens and many possible loops but I want to protect the user from the most obvious one, the A>B>A>B type.
(I don't care about greater loops like A>B>C>A>B>C and alikes)

To do that, I want to check the navigation stack top element and if the element is the same where we would go with a push, I would do a pop.

Problem is that I can't find anything on Google...

Tried:
Googling it, checking API docs, reading IntelliSense

EDIT:
There is a big set of screens and can't know the previous location solely based on the current one.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `GoRouter.of(context).location`

`GoRouter.of(context).location` gives you the current location

##### Example:

- Route A  has route path `/routeA`
- Route B has route path `/routeB`

  ##### `GoRouter.of(context).location` will return either `/routeA` or `/routeB`

  Based on which you can make decision to `pop()` or `push()` page

Comment: Sorry but the question was not exact enough. There is not only A and B but a huge set of routes and I don't know for certain what was the previous one based on the current one. This would only work if I had only A and B. Or if the chain was predefined. It is not.